# Add timestamp to a filename during rsync

Tags: linux, rsync

I'm using rsync to move files uploaded on an extern system to a internal system. However I recently had someone upload two different files with the same name. Meaning they had a file from Month1 and one from Month2, but both were named *mylog.csv*.

I'm currently moving them between directories with rsync, which sees the change and overwrites the prior upload.

```
rsync -rutv --remove-source-files /external/intake/ /internal/intake/
```

The external path does contain additional sub-directories, ie:

```
/external/intake/project/user/(additional directories they may build while uploading files)
```

What I would like to do is timestamp files as they are moved between directories. This way I would at least see that there were two of them if they were copied over with the copy time stamp. If I could get a result something like `20201009:0800-mylog.csv` and `202001009:0810-mylog.csv`. The full path after the move would be something like:

```
/external/intake/project/user/(possible additional directories)/$time-file.txt
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rsync does not support and hooks or renaming structures, but I think you have several options.

## Option 1 -- pure rsync

If you're willing to change your output format slightly, you could create a new directory for every move, with a timestamp. When you have something like

```
/somedir
    /somedir/oldtime
        /somedir/oldtime/file1.txt
        /somedir/oldtime/file2.txt
...
/external/intake
    /external/intake/file1.txt (NEWER)
```

You could sync to it by doing something like `rsync -rutv --remove-source-files /external/intake/ /somedir/newtime --link-dest="/somedir/oldtime" --compare-dest="/somedir/oldtime"`.
The resulting structure would be

```
/somedir
    /somedir/oldtime
        /somedir/oldtime/file1.txt
        /somedir/oldtime/file2.txt
    /somedir/newtime
        /somedir/newtime/file1.txt
        /somedir/newtime/file2.txt -> /somedir/oldtime/file2.txt (LINKED)
```

Because of the links, you don't have to have any extra disk usage, so you avoid quickly exploding size, but it is a bit different than what you requested exactly.

## Option 2 -- bash

This will perform exactly as you asked, but it won't use rsync. You'll miss out on the speed-ups related to rdiff, but since you're not really using it for that, it shouldn't effect anything.

Here's a short bash script that should do as you require. It should duplicate behavior exactly as you asked.

```
#! /bin/bash
# command syntax: arg1 is source, arg2 is dest

# Get timestamp in nice format
dir=$(pwd)
time=$(date +"%m-%d-%Y")
# Loop through each file
cd $1
find . -type f |
while read -r line
do
    cd $dir
    echo "processing $line"
    # Check if it exisits
    if [ -f "$2/$line" ]; then
        # Copy over, but add timestamp
        base=$(basename "$line")
        fdir=$(dirname "$line")
        echo "cp $1/$line $2/$fdir/$time-$base"
        cp "$1/$line" "$2/$fdir/$time-$base"
    else
        # Copy over, no timestamp
        echo "cp $1/$line $2/$line"
        cp "$1/$line" "$2/$line"
    fi
done

# Remove source here if you really want
```

Its pretty ugly, but it works. For what its worth, this is just a skeleton. I tested it in very limited cases, and ensure it works all the way before using.

Comment: Looks good, I haven't tested it yet. Thanks for confirming that rsync couldn't do this.